# Deleting specific columns of each row

Tags: python

i'm new to python and right now i'm out of ideas.
What i'm trying to: *i got a file*

example:

```
254   578       name1      *--21->28--*      secname1
854   548       name2      *--21->28--*      secname2
944   785       name3      *--21->28--*      secname3
1025  654       name4      *--21->28--*      secname4
```

between those files are a lot of spaces and i wan't to remove specific spaces between "name*" and "secname*" for each row. I don't know what to do to as seen in the example remove the character/spaces 21 -> 28

What i got so far:

```
fobj_in = open("85488_66325_R85V54.txt")
fobj_out = open("85488_66325_R85V54.txt","w")

for line in fobj_in:



fobj_in.close()
fobj_out.close()
```

At the end it should look like:

```
254   578       name1            secname1
854   548       name2            secname2
944   785       name3            secname3
1025  654       name4            secname4
```

Comment: What do you use `fobj_out` for?

Comment: I use it to write to the file, in another function i used it like that "fobj_out.write(str(i) + ": " + line)"

Comment: by `*--21->28--*` do you mean that there are 21-28 spaces between `name` and `secname`?

And I assume that there is no further text after `secname`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove characters by specific index positions you have to use slicing

```
for line in open('85488_66325_R85V54.txt'): 
    newline = line[:21] + line[29:]
    print(newline)
```

removes the characters in column 21:28 (which are all whitespaces in your example)

Comment: Thanks, after executing your code it looks fine in the shell. But after i edited the code to write it to a file, the file was empty:
`fobj_in = open("file.txt")
fobj_out = open("file.txt","w")

for line in fobj_in:
    newline = line[:213] + line[243:]
    fobj_out.write(newline)

fobj_in.close()
fobj_out.close()`

Comment: maybe use the parameter 'a', instead of 'w'. The values will be replaces if you use `open("file.txt","w") `. Use `open("file.txt","a")`

Comment: You cannot read a line from and write a line into the same textfile within one iteration (as @MohitMotwani wrote, it's overwriting). you have to read first all lines, buffer them to a variable and write that variable in another loop back to the file

Comment: Okey, instead of writing everything to the same file, i let the function create a new file with another name and it works now .. thanks for helping @gehbiszumeis

Answer (score 2):

Just split the line and pop the element you don't need.

```
fobj_in = open('85488_66325_R85V54','r')
fobj_out = open('85488_66325_R85V54.txt', 'a')
for line in fobj_in:
     items = line.split()
     items.pop(3)
     fobj_out.write(' '.join(items)+'\n')
fobj_in.close()
fobj_out.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the string object's `split` method, like so:

```
f = open('my_file.txt', 'r')
data = f.readlines()
final_data = []
for line in data:
    bits = line.split()
    final_data.append([bits[0], bits[1], bits[2], bits[4]])
```

Basically I'm just illustrating how to use that `split` method to break each line into individual chunks, at which point you can do whatever you wish, like print all of those bits and selectively discard one of the columns.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest a robust method to correct the input line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
# -----------------------------------
line='254   578       name1      *--21->28--*      secname1';
# -----------------------------------
def correctline(line,marker='*'):
    status=0;
    lineout='';
    for val in line:
        if val=='*': 
            status=abs(status-1);continue
        if status==0:
            lineout=lineout+val;
        elif status == 1:
            lineout=lineout
    # -----------------------------------
    while lineout.__contains__('  '):
        lineout=lineout.replace('  ',' ');
    return lineout
# ------------------------------------
print correctline(line)
```

Basically, it loops through the elements of the input file. When it finds some marker from which onward to skip the text, it skips it and finally just replaces too many spaces with one space.

Answer (score 1):

If the names are of varying lengths and you dont want to just remove a set number of spaces between them you can search for blank characters to find where `sname` begins and `name` ends:

```
# open file in "read" mode
fobj_in = open("85488_66325_R85V54.txt", "r")

# use readlines to create a list, each member containing a line of 85488_66325_R85V54.txt 
lines = fobj_in.readlines()

# For each line search from the end backwards for the first " " char
# when this char is found create first_name which is a list containing the
# elements of line from here onwards and a second list which is the elements up to
# this point. Then search for a non " " char and remove the blank spaces.
# remaining_line and first_name can then be concatenated back together using
# + with the desired number of spaces between then (in this case 12).
for line_number, line in enumerate(lines):
    first_name_found = False
    new_line_created = False
    for i in range(len(line)):
        if(line[-i] is " " and first_name_found is False):
            first_name = line[-i+1:]
            remaining_line = line[:-i+1]
            first_name_found = True
            for j in range(len(remaining_line)):
                if(remaining_line[-j-1] is not " " and new_line_created == False):
                    new_line = remaining_line[0:-j]+ " "*12 + first_name
                    new_line_created = True
                    lines[line_number] = new_line
```

then just write `lines` to `85488_66325_R85V54.txt`.

Comment: My goal wasn't to just remove all spaces between name1 and secname1. For example .. between name1 and secname1 are 40 spaces and i want to remove 15 spaces down from 40 spaces.(If you look at that picture, you see the blue marked spaces and i wanted them to be removed [Picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16KMcX7MIXAWEdKgJz6p6dphvuAl0Ponw/view)

Comment: So is it always 15 spaces you want to remove from each line?

Comment: No, its different, that's just an example. In the end the script needs to go through all the files that are in a specific folder and edit them. Each file has a unique name. While the script is running through all files i filter the name and search for that unique part in the files name to remove the correct amount of spaces in the right place. Right now the script is almost done.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to do it as follows:

`for line in fobj_in:
     setstring = line
     print(setstring.replace(" ", "")`

Comment: yeah but i need to define what i want to replace, it think that would remove every space in my document